# Can I prevent Internet Explorer 8 from running scripts until the page is loaded?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, javascript

When trying to veiw a number of different websites in IE8, I get the following error message:

```
HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element
                    before the child element is closed (KB927917)
```

On investigating the error message, it appears the script is trying to modify parts of the page before it is fully loaded.

Is there a setting in IE8 I can change to prevent scripts from running until the page is fully loaded?

EDIT: The sites in question used to work just fine, until I had to re-install IE8 for a seperate issue. Then they stopped working.

Comment: So, have you actually checked out MS' [KB927917](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917) yet?

Comment: Yes. That error is for IE7, not IE8, and produces a different error message. The underlying cause is the same (the script is trying to modify a page before its fully loaded). The suggested fix to to upgrade to IE8. I am running IE8.

Comment: You could also disable javascripting all together.  You could also upgrade to IE9

Comment: The sites need javascript to run. And no, I couldn't upgrade to IE.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no setting for this and would require modification of the browser such that it defers loading them just like how `defer` functions. With a proxy you could rewrite the scripts tag it to include the `defer="defer"` construct instead, which is as closest as you can get. Privoxy isn't capable of doing this and I'm not sure whether there are others, so you might need to write a simple proxy yourself...

Comment: So how is it the sites used to work until I had to re-install IE8?
(I know your comment came after my edit about that - it made me realise I should mention it!)

Comment: @TomW: Oh, that makes it quite different. Perhaps you have a different build of it, is it fully up-to-date? It could also be an unclean re-installation...

Comment: I downloaded it from Microsoft's website when I installed, so I assume its the most recent build. (It's version 8.0.6001.18702). It is possible the re-install didn't work properly.